# Windows 7 Compatibility tab grayed out

Tags: windows-7, compatibility

The compatibility tab on exe files and shortcuts on my Windows 7 Professional are all grayed out.

I wish to run as administrator. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different possibilities for this to happen, however if you are strictly looking for admin access and have privileges on your user account you can right click on the .exe file (or most files including shortcuts) and select the "run as administrator" option from the drop down menu. Hope this helps.

Comment: I cannot right click. Forgot to mention it's Windows7 on Bootcamp, and I needed to install the bootcamp drivers, and run them as administrator.

Comment: Oh. That might change things a bit, could still be a user privilege issue though, check any bootcamp settings available to see if it is blocking access.

Comment: Forgive me if that's vague it has been a while since i have used bootcamp.